# Laravel AuthenticateSession Middleware Multiple Guards

Tags: laravel

The Laravel `AuthenticateSession` middleware doesn't seem to function with multiple guards.

`$request->user()` returns `null` when there are multiple guards, which seems to be the problem.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are missing something. What are you trying to do? Where is the code that it is failing on?

Comment: Authenticate session should make sure that the user is logged in with the current password set. If multiple guards are defined, it doesn’t work.

Comment: Auth::guard('your_guard')->logoutOtherDevices($password); ?